# How to show text slowly on hover of button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you please tell me how to show text slowly on hover of button ? I tried using `transition:all 5s;` but I am facing one issue **my text coming from bottom to right** .I know the issue that text didn't get proper width due to that it is coming from bottom and when width is available then it comes on right.

is it possible to show only when width is available ? so that user will not see text is coming from bottom to right .

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/nividexoti/edit?html,css,output

```css
button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

button span {
  display: none;
}

button:hover {
  width: 80px;
  transition: all 5s;
}

button:hover span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>
        <i>||</i>
        <span>pause<span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `opacity:0` to `span` element of `button` and on `hover` apply `opacity:1` with `transition`. Refer :https://jsbin.com/nozomakuru/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

You could use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and set `overflow: hidden` on the button:

```css
button {
  /* Added */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* ----- */
  
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

button:hover {
  width: 80px;
  transition: all 5s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>
    <i>||</i>
    <span>pause</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set an animation-delay that will only appear once it's thick enough and play with the opacity:

```css
button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all 5s;
}

button span {
  display: none;
}

button:hover {
  width: 80px;
}

button:hover span {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
    <i>||</i>
    <span>pause</span>
</button>
```